# how to fix the jquery dailog box close after open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a usercontrol which open the jquery dialog. When the dialog box open, it close immediately. Would you tell me how to fix it.

My user control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

the code behind of the user control:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim textbox As TextBox = Me.Parent.FindControl("txtCustomer")

    Dim url As String = "openDailog('popOrder.aspx?Id=" & textbox.Text & "', 'Order', 800, 200);"
    LinkButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", url)

End Sub
```

My javascript:

```
function openDailog(url, name, width, height) {
 $('#dialog-box').dialog({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window,
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    max_height: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    width: width,
    title: name,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load(url);
    },
});


$('#dialog-box').dialog('open');
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LinkButton triggers a PostBack. Even if there is no `OnClick` attached to it. And after a PostBack, which is a page refresh, the modal is not open anymore. So you see it as a quick closing Dialog.
To fix this don't use a aspnet Control for opening the Dialog, or add `return false` to the LinkButton clienstide `onclick`.

```
Dim url As String = "openDailog('popOrder.aspx?Id=" & textbox.Text & "', 'Order', 800, 200); return false;"
```